# When developing an Eclipse plugin, how to get access to the project's Java Model and AST root node?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I am currently developing a plugin that'll make use of Eclipse's Java Model and Eclipse's Java Abstract Syntax Tree.

So what I am looking for is a way of getting though my plugin the Java Model root object and the current Java project's AST Root node:

```
public class SampleHandler extends AbstractHandler {
    public Object execute(ExecutionEvent event) throws ExecutionException {     
        IWorkbenchWindow window = HandlerUtil.getActiveWorkbenchWindowChecked(event);
                ??? how to get the current Java project Java Model? and the AST node?
        }
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I use the following to get the model:

```
public static IJavaModel prepareWorkspace() {
    IWorkspace workspace = ResourcesPlugin.getWorkspace();
    IWorkspaceRoot workspaceRoot = workspace.getRoot();
    IJavaModel javaModel = JavaCore.create(workspaceRoot);
    return javaModel;
}
```

You can find this and some other helpful Eclipse utility methods in [EclipseUtils.java](http://code.google.com/p/ext-c/source/browse/trunk/src/nz/ac/vuw/ecs/kcassell/utils/EclipseUtils.java) and [EclipseSearchUtils.java](http://code.google.com/p/ext-c/source/browse/trunk/src/nz/ac/vuw/ecs/kcassell/utils/EclipseSearchUtils.java).

Comment: Thanks! If software actually mirrors the organize that wrote it, as Conway's law suggests, I figure at IBM everything requires you to talk to a manager none of your friends ever heard about—Law of Demeter, anyone!?

Answer (score 3):

You can get the selection from within your handler, and then you can decide what to do with it:

```
ISelection sel = HandlerUtil.getCurrentSelection(event);
if (sel instanceof IStructuredSelection) {
    // check to see if it's empty first, though
    Object obj = ((IStructuredSelection)sel).getFirstElement();
    // then have a look and see what your selection is.
}
```

If you have an IJavaElement, you can walk about the model until you find the point you are looking for.  If you have an IFile/IResource, you can use some of the JavaCore methods to get to the java model.

Answer (score 2):

See org.eclipse.jdt.core plugin and IJavaProject and JavaCore classes. Use JavaCore.create( [IProject] ) to get IJavaProject and go rom there.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at this...

http://code.google.com/a/eclipselabs.org/p/javadocasumlview/source/browse/trunk/JavadocAsUmlAPI/src/main/java/utils/CompilationUnitResolverHelper.java

and

http://code.google.com/a/eclipselabs.org/p/javadocasumlview/source/browse/trunk/JavadocAsUmlAPI/src/main/java/utils/CompilationUnitResolverCache.java

Basically

- the selection context is mostly a compilation unit which itself is a `ITypeRoot`
- look for `ASTParser` or `SharedASTProvider` for a good starting point

Good Luck!